# Why do we neglect the hydrostatic pressure difference in a hydraulic lift?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

If we have a simple hydraulic lift with one piston which we push down (piston A), and the other piston (piston B) which is **below** the first one, why do we neglect the hydrostatic pressure difference in our equations?

[image]

Textbooks give the following equation: $$\frac{F_b}{A_b} = \frac{F_a}{A_a}$$

But why shouldn't that be like the following?: $$\frac{F_b}{A_b} = \frac{F_a}{A_a} + \rho g h$$

where *h* is the height difference between the pistons.

In short, why don't we consider the hydrostatic pressure difference due to the weight of the fluid in the vertical columns of a hydraulic lift and only consider the pressure due to the weights above the pistons?